Azure batch account , node unable to download the resource file using Managed Identity
Azure batch account , node unable to download the resource file using Managed Identity.
Below are my batch account settings.
I have a batch account , with linked auto storage , the authentication mode for auto storage is  BatchManagedIdentity. I have enabled the system identity for batch account. In auto storage I have uploaded application package.
One of the function app programmatically creates the CloudTasks and adds it to the batch job.
The Task uses a resource file which is in separate storage account not in the auto storage. So far I was passing the SAS url of the storage for the resource file and it was working but now I have disabled shared access key authentication for storage and want to use the managed identity. Accordingly I have changed my code to use identity instead of SAS as shown below.
  string subscriptionId = EnvironmentVariableAccessor.AccessEnvironmentVariable(Constants.SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
  string identityName = EnvironmentVariableAccessor.AccessEnvironmentVariable(Constants.BATCH_USER_MANAGED_IDENTITY);
  string identityResourceId = $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/{identityName}";
  var identity = new ComputeNodeIdentityReference() { ResourceId = identityResourceId };
  ResourceFile resourceFile = ResourceFile.FromStorageContainerUrl(inputContainerUrl, identityReference: identity, filePath: null, blobPrefix: blobName);

But I am getting below error while executing the task.
Miscellaneous error encountered while listing one of the specified Azure Blob container(s)

Auto Storage Setting

Pool Identity Setting

same user identity I am using in the function app code Resource file while creating the Task
Below is the RBAC for the identity to access the resource file


SMI on the Batch account has no bearing on identities used in the pool. This is noted in the green tip box on the corresponding Batch pool identities documentation.
